# opcode of %ebx register

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, machine-code, instruction-set

I wrote the following assembly program to get the opcode of various registers:

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
add $1,%eax                                                          
add $1,%ebx                                                          
add $1,%ecx                                                          
add $1,%edx                                                          
add $1,%esp                                                             
add $1,%ebp                                                             
add $1,%esi                                                          
add $1,%edi                                                          
int $0x80
```

I compile and link with:

```
gcc -c prog.s && ld prog.o
```

and the object dump is:

```
0000000000400078 <_start>:
  400078:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  40007b:   83 c3 01                add    $0x1,%ebx
  40007e:   83 c1 01                add    $0x1,%ecx
  400081:   83 c2 01                add    $0x1,%edx
  400084:   83 c4 01                add    $0x1,%esp
  400087:   83 c5 01                add    $0x1,%ebp
  40008a:   83 c6 01                add    $0x1,%esi
  40008d:   83 c7 01                add    $0x1,%edi
  400090:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

I would expect `%ebx` to have opcode `c1`, which is is not the case. So my question is: why is `c3` the opcode of `%ebx` for these `add` instrucions?

Comment: cross-site duplicate of [Why are first four x86 GPRs named in such unintuitive order?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5121).  x86 register codes go EAX, ECX, EDX, EBX, ESP, EBP, ESI, EDI.

Comment: And BTW, that's not the opcode, that's the ModRM byte that encodes the operand (addressing mode and register) for [`83 /0` `add r/m32, imm8`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html).  The `/r` field of the ModRM byte is `0`, used as extra opcode bits.

Comment: Those links were very helpful, thanks.

Comment: related, with some information on the order: [Do we also refer to the registers RAX, RBX etc as R1, R2 and so on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9129933/995714). In nasm you can get the number in the modrm byte as expected if you use r0, r1, r2... with the option `%use altreg`