# Are some general purpose registers faster than others?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

In x86-64, will certain instructions execute faster if some general purpose registers are preferred over others?

For instance, would `mov eax, ecx` execute faster than `mov r8d, ecx`? I can imagine that the latter would need a REX prefix which would make the instruction fetch slower?

What about using `rax` instead of `rcx`? What about `add` or `xor`? Other operations? Smaller registers like `r15b` vs `al`? `al` vs `ah`?

AMD vs Intel? Newer processors? Older processors? Combinations of instructions?

Clarification: Should certain general purpose registers be preferred over others, and which ones are they?

Comment: The only difference I know of is that some instructions have *smaller* encodings if certain registers are used.  For instance, `add al, 7; add dl, 7; add r12b, 7` are 2, 3, 4 bytes respectively, the last due to the REX prefix as you note.  This may slow down the time to fetch the instructions, or waste cache space, but I'm not aware that it makes any difference in the time to actually execute the instructions.

Comment: My understanding is that the machine has a large number of anonymous internal registers, onto which the architectural registers are mapped in a dynamic fashion (register renaming), so I can't think of any way that any one architectural register could be inherently faster than any other.

Comment: And in code that will interact with higher-level languages, there are the register saving conventions to consider.  This may mean that `rbx` is "slower" than `rcx` simply because you would have to save and restore it at the start and end of your function.  Or it can go the other way; if you call many other functions, `rbx` may end up being *faster* because you don't have to save and restore it around every function call you make.  But that's nothing to do with the machine itself, of course.

Comment: On (nearly all) modern systems with register renaming, the CPU isn't really using your register names anyway - it will gladly use another General Purpose register to avoid stalls for you.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59869218/does-it-matter-which-registers-you-use-when-writing-assembly/59881332

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, architectural registers are all equal, and renamed onto a large array of physical registers.

(Except partial registers can be slower, especially high-byte AH/BH/CH/DH which are slow to *read* after writing the full register, on Haswell and later.  See [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660139) and also [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573502) for problems when writing 8-bit and 16-bit registers). *The rest of this answer is just going to consider 32/64-bit operand-size*.)

But some instruction require specific registers, like legacy variable-count shifts (without BMI2 shrx etc) require the count in CL.  Division requires the dividend in EDX:EAX (or RDX:RAX for the slower 64-bit version).

Using a call-preserved register like RBX means your function has to spend extra instructions saving/restoring it.

But of course there are perf differences if you need more instructions.  So lets assume all else is equal, and just talk about the uops, latency, and code-size of a single instruction just by changing which register is used for one of its operands.  **TL:DR: the only perf difference is due to instruction-encoding restrictions / differences.**  Sometimes a different register will allow / require (or get the assembler to pick) a different encoding, which will often be smaller / larger as a special case, and sometimes even executes differently.

Generally smaller code is faster, and packs better in the uop cache and I-cache, so unless you've analyzed a specific case and found a problem, favour the smaller encoding.  Often that means keeping a byte value in AL so you can use those special-case instructions, and avoiding RBP / R13 for pointers.

---

### Special cases where a specific encoding is extra slow, not just size

LEA with RBP or R13 as a base can be slower on Intel if the addressing mode didn't already have a `+displacement` constant.

e.g. `lea eax, [rbp + 12]` is encodeable as-written, and is just as fast as `lea eax, [rcx + 12]`.

But `lea eax, [rbp  + rcx*4]` can only be encoded in machine code as `lea eax, [rbp  + rcx*4 + 0]` (because of [addressing mode escape-code stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52522744/224132)), which is a 3-component LEA, and thus slower on Intel (3 cycle latency on Sandybridge-family instead of 1 cycle, see https://agner.org/optimize/ instruction tables and microarch PDF).  On AMD, having a scaled-index would already make it a slow-LEA even with `lea eax, [rdx + rcx*4]`

Outside of LEA, using RBP / R13 as the base in any addressing mode always requires a `disp8/32` byte or dword, but I don't think the actual AGUs are slower for a 3-component addressing mode.  So it's just a code-size effect.

---

Other cases include [Which Intel microarchitecture introduced the ADC reg,0 single-uop special case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51664369) where the short-form 2-byte encoding for `adc al, imm8` is 2 uops even on modern uarches like Skylake, where `adc bl, imm8` is 1 uop.

So not only does the `adc reg,0` special case not work for `adc al,0` on Sandybridge through Haswell, Broadwell and newer forgot (or chose not to) optimize how that encoding decodes to uops.  (Of course you *could* manually encode `adc al,0` using the 3-byte Mod/RM encoding, but assemblers will always pick the shortest encoding so `adc al,0` will assemble to the short form by default.)  Only a problem with byte registers; `adc eax,0` will use the `opcode ModRM imm8` 3-byte encoding, not 5-byte `opcode imm32`.

**For other cases of `op al,imm8`, the only difference is code-size, which only indirectly matters for performance.**  (Because of decoding, uop-cache packing, and I-cache misses).

See [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code) for more about special cases of code-size, like `xchg eax, ecx` being 1-byte vs. `xchg edx, ecx` being 2 bytes.

---

`add rsp, 8` can need an extra stack-sync uop if there hasn't been an explicit use of RSP or ESP since the last push/pop/call/ret (along the path of execution of course, not in the static code layout).  ([What is the stack engine in the Sandybridge microarchitecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture)).  This is why compilers like `clang` use a dummy push or pop to reserve / free a single stack slot: [Why does this function push RAX to the stack as the first operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773787/why-does-this-function-push-rax-to-the-stack-as-the-first-operation/37774474)

Comment: What about the high byte registers?

Comment: @harold: good point!  Even reading them is slow on Intel, even creating extra latency for the dep chain from the other operand to the output.  [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660139)  Hmm, IDK how much I want to expand this answer to go into partial-register penalties.  ([Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573502))

Comment: Another point I didn't mention: Intel P6 family (ending with Nehalem / Westmere in 2009) have "register read stalls", where there's a limit on how many "cold" registers can be read per clock cycle.  Most code reads regs that have been written recently so their values are still in the ROB (on P6 which doesn't use separate physical register file).  Agner Fog's microarch PDF covers this, and see the P6 section of [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806)

Answer (score 7):

[LEA will be slower with EBP, RBP, or R13 as the base](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) (PDF warning, page 3-22). But generally the answer is No.

Taking a step back, it's important to realize that since the advent of [register renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming) that architectural registers don't deal with actual, physical registers on most micro-architectures. For example, each Cascade Lake core has a register file of 180 integer and 168 FP registers.

Comment: It only makes LEA slower on Intel if the addressing mode didn't already have a `+displacement` constant.  e.g. `lea eax, [rbp + 12]` is encodeable as-written, and is just as fast as `lea eax, [rcx + 12]`.  The effect you're talking about is I think that `lea eax, [rbp  + rcx*4]` can only be encoded in machine code as `lea eax, [rbp  + rcx*4 + 0]` (because of [addressing mode escape-code stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52522744/224132)), which is a 3-component LEA, and thus slow on Intel.  On AMD, having a scaled-index would already make it a slow-LEA.

Comment: **TL:DR: the only perf difference is due to instruction-encoding restrictions / differences.**  Other cases include [Which Intel microarchitecture introduced the ADC reg,0 single-uop special case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51664369) where the short-form 2-byte encoding for `adc al, imm8` is 2 uops even on modern uarches like Skylake.  (For other cases of `op al,imm8`, the only difference is code-size, which indirectly matters for performance.

Answer (score -3):

You have stuffed too many questions altogether, however, if I understood the question well, you are confusing the processor architecture with the small but fast Register file, which fills in the speed gap between the processor and memory technologies. The register file is small enough that it can only support one instruction at a time, i.e. the current instruction, and fast enough that it can almost catch up with the processor speed.

I would like to build a short background, the naming conventions of these registers serves two purposes: one, it makes the older versions of the x86 ISA implementations compatible up till now, and two, every name of these registers has a special purpose to it besides its general purpose use. For example, the ECX register is used as a counter to implement loops i.e. instructions like JECXZ and LOOP uses ECX register exclusively. Though you need to watch out for some flags that you would not want to lose.

And now the answer to your question stems from the second purpose. So some registers would seem to be faster because these special registers are hardcoded into the processor and can be accessed much quicker, however, the difference should not be much.

And the second thing that you might know, not all instructions are of the same complexity, especially in x86, the opcode of instructions can be from 1-3 bytes and as more and more functionality is added to the instruction in terms of, prefixes, addressing modes, etc. these instructions start to become slower, So it is not the case that some registers are slower than other, it is just that some registers are encoded into the instruction and therefore those instructions run faster with that combination of register. And if otherwise used, it would seem slower. I hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: 1 instruction at a time?  Even Pentium was doing better than that in 1993.  Haswell and later can run 4 simple ALU instructions like `add reg,reg` instructions per clock if you pick 4 different destination registers.  That's 8 register reads per clock, 4 writes. See https://agner.org/optimize/, and https://uops.info/, e.g. https://www.uops.info/html-instr/ADD_01_R32_R32.html has links to the actual instruction sequences that were microbenchmarked.

Comment: I think we are talking about a uniprocessor here, where the CPU is shared among multiple processes and each one of them has their own address space. This address space is addressed using these Register file. And just to remind you that the question is not involving a parallel or a distributive system, but a uniprocessor where these registers are used for the currently executing instruction of a certain process.   Khattak

Comment: I *was* talking about a *single* Haswell/Skylake core which really can execute 4 instructions per clock on one core. https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client)#Individual_Core. (If I was talking about thread-level parallelism as well as instruction-level parallelism, I would have said a quad-core Haswell can execute 16 `add` instructions per clock across all its cores.)  Context switching has nothing to do with anything.  It happens so rarely compared to executing an instruction, like once per millions of instructions, and has no impact on register choice.

Comment: The question is so simple to get involved in a thread or instruction-level parallelism. What I said was that " It is not the case that some registers are slower than others, it is just that some registers are encoded into the instruction and therefore those particular registers if used with the instruction, the register would seem to run faster And if other combinations of Registers are used it would seem slower. If you have something on the speed of registers, that would really enlighten the environment here, cheers

Comment: I already posted an answer to this question a month ago, it's current the accepted answer.  I think it goes into plenty of detail about that point; yes the only thing that makes some registers faster (when there's a choice at all) is shorter instruction encodings for some registers, like 2-byte `cmp al, imm8`.  I agree with that part of your answer.  I was disagreeing with the part of your answer that claimed register files only need to support 1 instruction at a time.  You're the one that brought up threads/cores in the first place, I was just talking about superscalar pipelines.