# Performance impact of choice of registers in x86_64

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

I'm wondering, is there any comprehensive guidelines for how one should chose which registers to use, when generating custom x86_64 assembly code?

I know the basics about pipelining, and the implications of data-dependencies (including false dependencies when using smaller register without sign extension), but there are still details I'm unsure about. For example, when reading a chain of memory operands (ie. a set of nested pointers), is it better to reuse the same register, or different ones?

```
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbx]
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]
```

For reference, I'm writing a native compiler for a stack-based scripting language. At this point, the language still has to use it's own stack-structure for certain operations, so that following code would be to put the stack-top pointer from our internal "register" struct, into "rcx".

My initial instinct would have been to generate the code as seen above, to minimize the amount of registers that have to be utilized during this operation. However, IIRC correctly I noticed a stark deterioration in performance, compared to

```
mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbx]
mov         rdx,qword ptr [rcx]
mov         rax,qword ptr [rdx]
```

My best guess is that this might be better to pipeline, though I'm unsure how, as each instruction would depend on the result of the read memory from the previous one. And obviously, this complicates the process of writing the code-generator, as now many operations would need to potentially use multiple registers, especially when trying to setup the arguments for a function-call.

So I'd like to make sure to actually understand the "best practices" for performant register usage, for my case (and also in general). Can somebody clear up my confusion? Maybe there is some source that put this information together?

Comment: I would expect no difference, due to register renaming. Can you post some concrete timings with details on how to reproduce your findings?

Comment: @rustyx Unfortunately, it has been a while, and I have no proper documentation or code for the case I tested back then. I can see if I can recreate it, but I would also happily accept the answer "it shouldn't make a difference" for the general case, as this would allow me to drastically simplify my code-gen (by removing the need for many temporary registers for such operations).

Comment: AFAIK, the number of renamed registers is limited per cycle (actually, the number of µops) but the limite is relatively large on modern CPUs (AFAIK, the RAT can process 4 µops/cycle on Skylake). I expect the number of load ports to be generally smaller (2 on Skylake -- no more than 3 on very recent x86-64 CPUs). Thus, unless you massively rely on register renaming for all instructions, I do not expect a significant overhead. At least, not in hot rather-small loops. I wonder if this is also true on low-power/embedded/mobile x86-64 CPUs though.

Comment: Perhaps some later code had a false dependency on RCX (like `mov cl, [mem]` instead of `movzx ecx, byte [mem]`), so having the later `mov` instructions write different registers meant the false dependency was ready sooner.  Or a false dependency on RDX and the previous use of RDX was an even slower dependency chain, and writing it here broke that dependency.  There's nothing inherent about different named registers other than encoding limitations.  ([Are some general purpose registers faster than others?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62922332))

Comment: @JérômeRichard: I'm not aware of any out-of-order CPUs with renaming limits where `add` or `mov` to the same register repeatedly could issue from the front-end faster or slower than to independent registers.  (e.g. all x86 CPUs can rename the same register + FLAGS pipeline-width times / cycle.) There should be zero difference between these sequences in terms of execution resources required and how they go through the pipeline.  They're dependent loads either way (limited by 4 or 5 cycle load-use latency), so front-end or back-end throughput are only a factor when considering surrounding code.

Comment: One possible difference is maybe being able to free an older PRF entry at some point, but that probably can't happen until these loads retire.  Until then, an exception, interrupt, or mispredict might need to roll back to a state where the previous write of RDX is the architectural value.  (See https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/ re: register-file capacity vs. ROB (reorder buffer) capacity being a limit for how far out-of-order exec can see.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Must have been something like that then. This was not a micro-benchmark, but a real-world measurement of a whole games script-execution overhead. The differences where in the range of ~50% IIRC; but in such a context it could have easily been caused by some false dependency in code before or after. Didn't even know about the movzx thing back then. Anyhow, I'll just go with simplifying my code by avoiding extra registers in such cases.